# Uniform continuity of $\sin(xy)$

Tags: real-analysis, epsilon-delta, uniform-continuity

> Determine whether $f(x,y) = \sin(xy)$ is uniformly continuous on
>   $x,y\geq 0$.

Now aside from the definition, I have some trouble even starting with this exercise. I know $|\sin(t)| \leq 1$ forall $t$, and $\sin(t) \leq t$ for positive $t$, but I am just guessing if these could be of use. I am inclined to think that it is uniformly continuous at least.

More generally, how should one approch uniform continuity? I have seen a lot of different approaches, but cannot seem to find a pattern.

Comment: It's actually the case that $x \mapsto \sin(x^2)$ is not uniformly continuous on $[0, \infty)$.

Comment: @Patrick Stevens So let $P = (x,y)$ and $P'=(x,x)$ be two points, we can show that $d(P,P') < \delta$ but $d(f(P),f(P')) \geq \epsilon$, which shows that $f$ is not uniformly continuous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose $(x_{1,n},y_{1,n}) = (n, 2\pi + \pi/(2n))$ and $(x_{2,n},y_{2,n}) = (n, 2\pi ).$

Then as $n \to \infty$

$$||(x_{1,n},y_{1,n}) - (x_{2,n},y_{2,n})|| = \frac{\pi}{2n} \to 0,$$

but

$$|\sin(x_{1,n}y_{1,n}) - \sin(x_{2,n}y_{2,n})| = |\sin(2\pi n+ \pi/2) - \sin(2 \pi n)| = 1 \not\to 0.$$

Thus, $\sin(xy)$ is not uniformly continuous on $[0,\infty) \times [0,\infty)$.

The selection of this particular sequence of points was motivated by an attempt to find a bound for proving uniform continuity.

In particular,

$$\begin{align}|\sin(x_1y_1) - \sin(x_2y_2)| &= 2 \left|\sin\left(\frac{x_1y_1-x_2y_2}{2}\right) \right|\left|\cos\left(\frac{x_1y_1+x_2y_2}{2}\right) \right| \\ &\leqslant |x_1y_1 - x_2y_2| \\ &\leqslant |x_1||y_1 - y_2| + |y_2||x_1 -x_2|\end{align}.$$

The bound here fails to be small if $|x_1|$ is sufficiently large, despite the proximity of $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$.

Comment: @Erik Joensson: This shows that the function is not uniformly continuous, but may not answer your general question. There is no general procedure, but in the process of trying to prove uniform continuity by some bounding argument one might see why it will fail. Then one may discover a sequence of points which can be made arbitrarily close, but for which the distance between images will not converge to 0.  If there is interest I can show how this line of reasoning applies here.

Comment: Yes, sorry for taking too long. Although I do understand the reasoning when given the points which contradicts uniform continuity, to actually obtain these (somewhat artificial) points from the beginning is the tricky part; Or rather, to intuitively see that the function in question is not uniformly continuous. It might just be an issue of revisiting examples and build up intuition (much like proofs in general).

Comment: Thanks,  I expanded the answer along these lines.